# check that one time range enters another

Tags: c#

I have the two dates variables: `startWork` and `endWork`.
I need to define whether person includes worked in the period from 23 hours to 05 hours.
For example:
`startWork.Hour` | `endWork.Hour`  | `result`

```
    21              5            Yes
    22              3            Yes
    12              21           No
    23              8            Yes
    21              8            Yes
    7               9            No
```

My code:

```
if(startWork.Hour >= 23 && startWork.Hour <=5)
     return true;

if(endWork.Hour >= 23 && endWork.Hour <=5)
     return true;
```

But, this code is not coverage all variants.

Comment: I suggest changing your program so you store actual `DateTime` values instead of just hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to match `X >= 22 AND x <= 6` condition...

Try following:

```
public static bool CheckWorkHours(int start, int end)
{
    if(start >= 23 || start <= 5)
        return true;

    if(end >= 23 || end <= 5)
        return true;

    if(start < 23 && end > 5 && start > end)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Quick test with your sample data:

```
var input = new[] { 
    new { start = 21, end = 5},
    new { start = 22, end = 3},
    new { start = 12, end = 21},
    new { start = 23, end = 8},
    new { start = 21, end = 8},
    new { start = 7, end = 9},
};

foreach (var item in input)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}: {2}", item.start, item.end, CheckWorkHours(item.start, item.end));
```

prints

```
21-5: True
22-3: True
12-21: False
23-8: True
21-8: True
7-9: False
```

Answer (score 1):

It's best if you can use actual `DateTime` objects for the start and end work parameters, as they are indeed, points in time. Barring that, you can always add 24 to the rolled-over values to make them linear, something like:

```
public bool CheckWorkHours(int start, int end, int checkStart, int checkEnd)
{
    if (checkStart > checkEnd)
        checkEnd += 24;

    if (start > end)
        end +=24;

    //did he start working after (or on) checkEnd?
    if (start >= checkEnd)
        return false;

    //did he end working before (or on) checkStart?
    if (end <= checkStart)
        return false;

    // he did indeed work during the interval
    return true;
}
```

Now the checks are straight-forward. If the person worked in the interval, he must start before the interval is over, and he must end working after the interval started.
That can be expressed in a one liner, like

```
return ((start < checkEnd) && (end > checkStart));
```

but when using date maths, I try to be as verbose as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should use DateTime like Dai suggested in his comment.

```
bool IsIn_23_To_5_Limits(DateTime startWork, DateTime endWork)
{
    if (startWork >= endWork)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("You can't stop working before start working.");
    }

    // startWork after 23:00
    // endWork before 05:00
    // endWork is immediately on the next day after startWork
    return startWork.Hour >= 23 && endWork.Hour < 5 && startWork.Day == endWork.Day - 1;
}
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that. I assumed we wanted the work period to be strictly within 23-5.